# VB DataGridView 1 Row selection

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a problem . When I load my form with my datagridview , I want the data to be transferred to the text fields when I click on the > at the most left of the datagridview.
Now, I have to select the content in the rows itself to select a row. How do I set it so it selects row based on the most left row selector? instead of having me click on the contents of the row  ? dtguser_CellContentClick makes me select based on the content click right? What should it be if I want to select by entire row?

```
Private Sub dtguser_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As         System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dtguser.CellContentClick
    If GroupBox3.Enabled = False Then
    Else


        'this code will simply pass the value from the specific row selected by the user
        lblid.Text = dtguser.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value
        serial.Text = dtguser.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value
        fname.Text = dtguser.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value
        lname.Text = dtguser.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value
        gender.Text = dtguser.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value
        address.Text = dtguser.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value
        contact.Text = dtguser.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value
        course.Text = dtguser.CurrentRow.Cells(6).Value
        datestart.Text = dtguser.CurrentRow.Cells(7).Value
        datecomplete.Text = dtguser.CurrentRow.Cells(8).Value
        datecertify.Text = dtguser.CurrentRow.Cells(9).Value
        nationality.Text = dtguser.CurrentRow.Cells(10).Value
        email.Text = dtguser.CurrentRow.Cells(11).Value
        certification.Text = dtguser.CurrentRow.Cells(12).Value
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What it the datasource you are setting to the `DataGridView`?

Comment: How do I check which datasource I am setting?

Comment: Post the code where you are setting the `datagridview.DataSource` property. How are you populating the grid?

Comment: `dtgrd.DataSource = publictable` This data is from a Mysql Table. Does this help?

Comment: Does `dtguser_CellContentClick` fire when you click `>`?

Comment: What does 'fire' mean? I click > but nothing happens. It just selects the row. I have to click the content inside to only have the data passed to the input fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to select the entire row set the selection mode to `FullRowSelect`.

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

If you want to get the data when you click the RowHeader (> button) then subscribe to the `RowHeaderMouseClick` event.

```
dataGridView1.RowHeaderMouseClick += new DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler(dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick);

Private Sub dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs)
    // put your code for copying row data into the textboxes.
End Sub
```

Comment: I have already set the SelectionMode to FullRowSelect. It does the job of selecting the entire row. But the data is not passed to my input fields. The data is only passed to the input fields when I click the content Inside the datagrid view. I want to pass data over by clicking small button on the most left of each row to select them

Comment: it works on vb, but you have to convert it from c# to vb.net first. This one is a useful link. http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: Thanks, But I am having problems. Error message Declaration Expected?

Comment: The code is just a sample code. You have to replace the `dataGridView1` with yours.